# Install NTLK modules under Python 3.7.1 without internet ( offline )

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, sql-server-2017

Had a problem of how to install Install NLTK python modules under Python 3.7.1 for SQL 2017 ( CU22 ), but had no direct internet access ( i.e. offline ).

So how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that appears to work OK :

(1) Go to https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/refs/heads/gh-pages.zip  & download zip file (600 MB).

(2) Dig down into the zip file, and find the required packages located at :

```
nltk_data-gh-pages.zip\nltk_data-gh-pages\packages\
```

(3) Create a directory either

```
C:\ntlk_data   ( this is a default search path for nltk )
```

- or -

  D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.<*instance_name*>\PYTHON_SERVICES.3.7\nltk_data

(4) For the package/s, copy the .zip file, its .XML file and then also extract the .zip file so it is an uncompressed directory.

For example punkt module, final form should look like this :

```
c:\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt.zip 
c:\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt\<and_sub_dirs_and_files> 
c:\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt.xml
```

(5)  Run TSQL code to confirm it can see the punkt module :

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script =N'   

import nltk 

x = nltk.data.find("tokenizers/punkt") 
print(x) 
'
```

You should get an output similar to this if it can see the punkt modules on disk :

```
STDOUT message(s) from external script:  

Express Edition will continue to be enforced. 
C:\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt\PY3
```

HTH someone!